# Starter project: webpack vs ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I saw starter projects for nodejs in Github, some of them using `ts-node` to run typescript files with node, and others using webpack to compile with typescript plugins and using `nodemon-webpack-plugin` to run the nodejs application.

I wonder which approach is recommended to use in 2020?